# Codeception don't clear cookies for specific scenarios

Tags: php, codeception

I'm using BDD in codeception and I know that cookies can be configured in the `codeception.yml` by

```
- clear_cookies: true #or false
```

I only want to clear cookies for specific set of scenarios or 1 feature file. Would this be possible

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are specific WebDriver commands to clear cookies. I don't know what they are off the top of my head. I wish the manual was more searchable.